# Use memcache on another IP

Tags: php, memcached

OK, here's my problem, I have 1 main server with a measly 128M of RAM. I also have a few other servers but they cannot support certain things making them not usable for a web server (not ideal for development (technical reason)). But the thing is that these servers have 4GB of ram. I want to put them to some good use and allow them to be used as memcached buckets?

Is this possible?

Of course you will think I am crazy for not using the 4GB server but I am not able to as the service provider disallows certain ports (25 is the one causing me issues as my web application requires mail).

I am using PHP. Please tell me, if this can work then what I need to install if I am not using the memcached server on my web server.

Also what ports will I have to forward?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application needs memory, run it on those servers anyway!  Use your server that has full access to the internet as nothing more than a gateway to those servers.

You can do this a variety of ways, from simple routing, NAT, proxying, or even just mapping some ports over.

Comment: wait, I can guess I just need to install the libraries right? But... is there any security risk in this?

Comment: @MuqMan, Security risk in what?  You're in control of all three servers, and they network they're on, yes?  No, there is no inherent security risk in routing.  That's how the internet works.  And as far as proxying and what not... that's a common way to load balance.

Comment: I cannot use the one with more ram but I want to reduce the load and make it faster without using more ram on the 128M one. The 128M works fine but I cannot make it as fast as I can the 4G one but I CANNOT use the 4G one because my app REQUIRES smtp which the ISP i have the 4G on disallows (i own the server at home (the 4G))

Comment: ok so no risk but is there anything specific to this. how would I install the libraries only?

Comment: Wait, these three servers are not on the same network?  Don't use memcached over the internet... that will be quite slow, and defeats much of the purpose, generally.  Are you sending mail or receiving it?  Again, in any case, you can send that mail through your server elsewhere.  And... what libraries are you talking about?  Be specific.

Comment: sending. No, not same network *2 servers, im sorry if i conveyed 3. Sending is blocked by my ISP because of spam issues

Comment: Ok, so you have a memory-hungry application.  You have one server on your home network, and it has 4GB of RAM.  You have a server out on the internet somewhere, probably a VPS, with 128MB of RAM allocated.  Your memory-hungry application cannot be split into pieces and needs to send mail, but your ISP won't let you use **outgoing port 25** on the network your 4GB server is on.  Is that correct?  If so, again, simply use your 128MB server to send mail.  You can still send from your 4GB server... direct mail to the other server for relay.  Very simple.

Comment: but how would I do that without using cookies? I mean I don't want the user to be able to see the content with cookies as it requires email verification...

Comment: wait split in 2 pieces? Well not sure. Memory hungry, it depends on the load, I can sometimes go upto advance of 75% of the memory usage. Or will it just be more prudent to upgrade my plan?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17368/discussion-between-brad-and-muqman)

Comment: ok, i get your point. Right now I am not ready to do the complicated setup. Sorry. I'm a bit confused right now too. I will send you a message when I come to a consensus. Thanks anyway.